# Prepend and append text input field with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, prepend, tampermonkey

I've searched and searched and can't seem to find an answer to this so please forgive me if I'm asking a question that's already been answered.

I use [Tampermonkey for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en). It's the Chrome version of Greasemonkey. I'm a frequent user of a forum at http://forum.xda-developers.com. Whenever I go to post a reply on that forum I like to change the font. The reply editor is somewhat like the editor here on Stackoverflow-- a code editor. So when you change the font what it does is wrap font tags around your text in your editor's text field like this example below:

```
[FONT="Arial"]This is a reply.[/FONT]
```

Now what I'd like to do is use Javascript or jQuery to automatically prepend [FONT="Arial"] and append [/FONT] to the editor's text input field upon page load.

So, that being said, what Javascript or jQuery would I use to automatically prepend and append that text upon page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is something like this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var originalData = $('textarea').val();
  $('textarea').val('[FONT="Arial"]' + originalData + '[/FONT]');
});
```

```css
/*unnecessary css, just for asthetics of code snippet*/
textarea{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Some text that is already in here</textarea>
```

UPDATE WITH VANILLA JAVASCRIPT:

```js
document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').setAttribute("onclick", "myWrappingFunction()");

function myWrappingFunction() {
  var originalData = document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').value;
  document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').value = '[FONT="Arial"]' + originalData + '[/FONT]';                        
}
```

```css
/*unnecessary css, just for asthetics of code snippet*/
textarea{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname">I am the nextarea with id vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes but that seems to replace all the text in the text area. I'd like to leave the text that's already present in the text area and just prepend and append that text around the existing text. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes!! That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know how to change from

    $(document).ready(function() {

to make the javascript only happen when clicking an element like this?

    id="vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname"

Comment: @MisterPyrrhuloxia: yup, updated answer above with just vanilla js

Comment: So I think that I don't want the prepend/append event to happen till after I click on the element id "vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname". I used your vanilla javascript above and it didn't seem to do that. Instead, no prepending or appending happens when I click on the vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname element.

Comment: @MisterPyrrhuloxia, edited vanilla js section to accommodate change of scope: prepend and append on click of textarea instead of on load of page

Comment: So I just used this and it didn't work:

function myWrappingFunction() {
  var originalData = document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').value;
  document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').value = '[FONT="Arial"]' + originalData + '[/FONT]';                        
}

It doesn't look like you updated the vanilla javascript section. It appears to the same as your first vanilla javascript. And thanks for your help, by the way!

Comment: did you put the `onclick` function on the `textarea`? << this is in the html portion.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. What do you mean? I'm not building a webpage. I'm using a Chrome extension called Tampermonkey that modifies my interaction with the webpage with javascript. This is exactly what I have in that script:

function myWrappingFunction() {
  var originalData = document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').value;
  document.getElementById('vB_Editor_001_popup_fontname').value = '[FONT="Ubuntu"]' + originalData + '[/FONT]'; 
}

Comment: ahhh, i understand what you're asking for now. you're not allowed to touch the html unless its through javascript right? i updated my answer to suit your needs. let me know if it works for you. (my answer before required the manipulation of the actual html, which you apparently do not have access to)

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't seem to be working. Here is the error I get in the Chrome console when I try to click on that element:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: myWrappingFunction is not defined"

Comment: I think the problem is that the "textarea" doesn't have a "value" in the element tag. I just looked at the full element for the textarea and here it is:

<textarea name="message" id="vB_Editor_001_textarea" style="width:100%; height: 315px; padding:0; margin:0;" rows="10" cols="60" tabindex="1" dir="ltr" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on">[QUOTE=mgbotoe;62176640]That's a lot to disabled. Will location base apps run normally?

Sent from my Nexus 6 using Tapatalk[/QUOTE]

</textarea>

Comment: `textarea` always have a value attribute, like a `textbox` always has one. sorry, ive run out of ideas .___. good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can [inject jquery](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2011/04/23/inject-jquery-onto-any-site/) to the page (if it's not already part of the page) and use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textAreaID').val('[FONT="Arial"]This is a reply.[/FONT]');
});
```